# Getting a blank data report vb6

Tags: vb6, report

I am new to vb6. I am working to create the invoice generation application. I am using data report to show the generated invoice.
The step by step working of process is:

Entering the data in to Invoice and ItemsInvoice  tables.
Then getting the maxId using (Adodc) from the data base to show the last generated Invoice.

Then passing the max Id as parameter to the data report which is showing the invoice according to the invoice id.

It is working fine when I first time generate invoice. Now for 2nd invoice without closing application I am getting a blank data report. For data report I am using dataenvironment.

I am guessing the reason the data report is blank is because there was no record for that Id, but actually the record is inserting in the database.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your data set is getting configured, but it sounds like you have a single record in the data and aren't reloading it properly.  If your report is manually moving through the recordset and only showing info based on the ID parameter you are passing it and then using the same recordset for the second report, you probably just need to `MoveFirst` on the recordset to put it back at the beginning.

Comment: thanks for the reply
but I think this is not the problem
I am sending you the source code that may help to understand the problem
the code may be split in to more than one post due to the limit of characters
rsInvoice.Recordset.AddNew
rsInvoice.Recordset.Fields(1).Value = Val(cmbcustomerId.List(cmbCustName.ListIndex))
rsInvoice.Recordset.Fields(2).Value = txtName.Text
rsInvoice.Recordset.Fields(3).Value = txtAddress.Text
rsInvoice.Recordset.Fields(4).Value = txtCity.Text
rsInvoice.Recordset.Fields(5).Value = Val(txtPhone.Text)
rsInvoice.Recordset.Fields(6).Value = Date

Comment: rsInvoice.Recordset.Update
rsInvoice.Refresh

rsMaxId.Recordset.Requery
rsMaxId.Refresh

If DataEnvironment1.rsInvoice_Grouping.State <> 0 Then DataEnvironment1.rsInvoice_Grouping.Close

' here I am getting the last inserted invoice ID  that is correct
 
DataEnvironment1.Invoice_Grouping (rsMaxId.Recordset.Fields(0).Value) 

 ' but here not getting the record for the inovice id I am passing The problem may be recordset of DataEnvironment1.rsInvoice_Grouping is not refreshing 

invoice.Refresh
invoice.Show

Answer (score 0):

Load the data environment and refresh the data report.
I am also generating report in the similar fashion. I faced this problem. Here's the solution

```
Load DataEnvironment1
With DataEnvironment1
     'Command1 is the command added to data environment where you fire query or 
     'set it to point to a table

    If .rsCommand1.State <> 0 Then .rsCommand1.Close
    .Command1 maxid         'parameter you pass to the recordset

End With
DataReport1.Refresh
DataReport1.Show
```

Thats it!
You are done. I m sure it will work. Do tell me if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the answer will still bother you, but if someone else have the same problem here is a example of how the problem works:
Imagine that there is a gate and a guard looking who is entering, when the first person (the first invoice) comes, the guard registers him, opens the gate (This is the event "Load DataEnvironmet") and then lets the guy pass. The guard believes that no one else would come and lets the door open (the instruction believes that the DataEnvironment ends and the value EOF becomes True), but when the second guy comes (the second invoice) the guard can't ask him who is (has, again, the value and lets it pass without registering him (this is the reason why the second invoice, and subsequent in while invoice would come blank). The solution is to close the gate ("Unload DataEnvironment") after a guy passes (After showing the data report).
The solution is the code given from Sangita above, but just before ending the sub you need to unload the DataEnvironment you were working on.
For me, it works. Sorry if the answer is not what you were looking for (and also if someone else can't understand what I'm writing, my English isn't very good). Just in case I will write the code with the solution

```
 Load DataEnvironment1
 With DataEnvironment1

   If .rsCommand1.State <> 0 Then
     .rsCommand1.Close
   End If
   .Command1 Value(ID)  

 End With
 DataReport1.Refresh
 DataReport1.Show
 Unload DataEnvironment1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try a refresh method like `data1.recordset.requery` or
`Data1.refresh`. This should work if you use data controls.